# AngularJS directive scope not resolved ("attr name is not defined" error)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Directive code

```
mymodule.directive('eicon', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            attr: '='
        },
        template: "test " + attr.name
    }
});
```

Html

```
<tr ng-repeat="e in entities">
    <td><eicon attr="e"></eicon></td>
</tr>
```

I've this error: `ReferenceError: attr is not defined`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attr` is accessible in scope, so you can access `scope.attr` in your controller or linking phase, or `{{attr}}` in templates. A simple solution is to change your template to

```
mymodule.directive('eicon', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            attr: '='
        },
        template: "test {{attr.name}}",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log(scope.attr);
        },
        controller: function (scope) {
          console.log(scope.attr);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are declaring isolated scope property `attr` you should be able to access `scope.attr` in template like this:

```
mymodule.directive('eicon', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            attr: '='
        },
        template: "test {{attr.name}}"
    }
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/YZ0aPqhkMlIIwmrkKK2v?p=preview

Comment: What if i need to access the code then? That template will depend on that value

Comment: What do you mean "access the code"? Are you talking about link function where you can manipulate with `scope.attr` object?

Comment: @dfsq you can check my answer for samples