# AngularJS : Pass $scope variable as directive attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to pass the $scope variable values to a custom directive as attribute, but it's not working.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<ul ng-repeat="q in questions">
        <li>
            {{q.question}} 
            <check-list name="{{q.id}}"></check-list>
        </li>
</ul>
```

The directive is `<check-list name={{q.id}}></check-list>`, and here is the directive code :

```
    app.directive('checkList',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template: function(elem,attrs){
            console.log(attrs.name);
            return '</br> <input type="radio" /> Yes </br> <input type="radio" /> No'
        },
        link:function(scope,elem,attrs){

        }
    };
})
```

I'm logging the attribute `attrs.name` but the value I'm getting is `"{{q.id}}"` instead of the actual value of `q.id`

Comment: `<check-list name="{{q.id}}"></check-list>` seems you miss double quotes?

Comment: Now I get `{{q.id}}`

Comment: BTW, you can refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394118/angularjs-directive-scope-not-resolved-attr-name-is-not-defined-error/28394192#28394192), it can solve your problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suppose what you want to do is injecting scope object from controller to your directive. So you can define your directive as

```
app.directive('checkList',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {
          name: "="
        }
        template: '{{name}}</br> <input type="radio" /> Yes </br> <input type="radio" /> No',
        link:function(scope,elem,attrs){

        }
    };
}
```

And in your view, you can reference your directive as

```
<check-list name="q.id"></check-list>
```

Answer (score 10):

In directives, attributes are just strings.

In a template function, all you can do is use the string value of the attribute.  If you want to use the evaluated or interpolated value of the attribute, you have a few options:

1)  Use an isolated scope

```
app.directive('checkList', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {
            name: '&'
        }
        template: '</br> <input type="radio" /> Yes </br>{{name()}} <input type="radio" /> No'
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

        }
    };
});

<ul ng-repeat="q in questions">
        <li>
            {{q.question}} 
            <check-list name="q.id"></check-list>
        </li>
</ul>
```

2) Inject $interpolate or $parse to evaluate the interpolation or expression manually in the link function

```
app.directive('checkList', function($interpolate) {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template: '</br> <input type="radio" /> Yes </br>{{name}} <input type="radio" /> No'
        link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
            scope.name = $interpolate(attrs.name)(scope);
        }
    };
});

<ul ng-repeat="q in questions">
        <li>
            {{q.question}} 
            <check-list name="{{q.id}}"></check-list>
        </li>
</ul>
```

2a) And finally, $parse

```
app.directive('checkList',function($parse){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template: '</br> <input type="radio" /> Yes </br>{{name}} <input type="radio" /> No'
        link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
            scope.name = $parse(attrs.name)(scope);
        }
    };
});

<ul ng-repeat="q in questions">
        <li>
            {{q.question}} 
            <check-list name="q.id"></check-list>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to pass "q.id" instead of name={{q.id}} provided $scope.q.id is defined in your corresponding controller.

```
 <check-list name="q.id"></check-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

Or pass the entire scope to your directive:

```
app.directive('checkList',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: true, //scope
        template: function(elem,attrs){
            console.log(attrs.name);
            return '</br> <input type="radio" /> Yes </br> <input type="radio" /> No'
        },
        link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
           var question = scope.q; //get your question here
        }
    };
})
```

I recommend you pass only reference type as argument to your directive. Do not pass primitive types (`q.id` may be an integer). Pass `question` instead. It's all about how angularjs utilizes prototypical inheritance.

`Scope` is a complex topic in angularjs. See this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes