# Send Query string parameters from html to angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I wrote an angular directive and i need to sent him some values from the query string.

for example :

```js
angular.module('TESTTTT', [])
  .directive('ngSomeDirective', function () {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
              test: '@'
          },
          templateUrl: '/someurl.html',
          link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              var acc = scope.$eval(attrs.test);
          },
      }

  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>


<ng-some-directive test="$location.search().keu;"></ng-some-directive>
```

I always get the value as string ("$location.search().keu;") and the actually value.

How can i send the query string value from the angular directive html declartion 
to the angular javascript?

Thanks in advance,
Jimi.

Answer (score 0):

Use '=' for expression binding:-

```
scope: {
              test: '='
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394118/angularjs-directive-scope-not-resolved-attr-name-is-not-defined-error/28394192#28394192).

If you want to use `test="$location.search().keu;"` in your view, define the scope variable as

```
scope: {
  test: '='
}
```

If you still want to use

```
scope: {
  test: '@'
}
```

you should change your view to `test="{{$location.search().keu;"}}`.

Last but not least, in your liking phase, access the test object by `scope.test`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I change to {{$location.search().keu}} and i always get an empty string. Did i need to declare something on the controller?

Comment: You need to inject $location into your controller and bind it to the scope as $scope.$location = $location

Comment: thanks.

I add this line to my controller:

function testCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.$location = $location;

and this line to the default.html 

<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
        <ng-test-header selected="{{$location.search().T}}"></ng-test-header>

this is the url : http://localhost/PortalClient/Default.html?T=sdsds

and i still get an ampty string.

Comment: can you try console log `$location.search()` to see what's the output?

Comment: Now we know current problem has nothing to with data binding because `$location.search()` is empty, you need try to figure out why `$location.search()` can not get the search part of current URL.

Comment: @user3770653 I suppose you can refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063673/whats-the-most-concise-way-to-read-query-parameters-in-angularjs) for how to use `$location.search()` or `routeParams`