# Undefined error in AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

```
.directive("checkboxsGroup", function() {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        // Determine initial checked boxes
        if (scope.arrays.indexOf(scope.item.value) !== -1) {
            elem[0].checked = true;
        }

        // Update array on click
        elem.bind('click', function() {
            var index = scope.arrays.indexOf(scope.item.value);
            // Add if checked
            if (elem[0].checked) {
                if (index === -1) scope.arrays.push(scope.item.value);
            }
            // Remove if unchecked
            else {
                if (index !== -1) scope.arrays.splice(index, 1);
            }
            // Sort and update DOM display
           /* scope.$apply(scope.array.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a - b
            }));*/

        });
    }
}
})
**my html code**
 <div  ng-repeat="colors in frame_product_options.color_list">
<input type="checkbox" checkboxs-group />{{colors.color_name}}
 <input type="button" name="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"  ng-click="frame_color_img(colors.id)" value="Save">
   </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="clrcheckboxvalues" ng-model="frame.clr_code" ng-init="frame.clr_code=arrays">
```

Comment: there is no `scope.arrays` defined in your code, right?

Comment: yes bro..but i don't know how to overcome this problem.i have another one directive in another name like checkboxGroup.in this i just use scope.array.it's working fine..what's wrong with my code

Comment: i got this error while run this above code."Error: scope.arrays is undefined"

Comment: Can you show me the code that working directive?

Comment: about how to pass variable to directive, you can check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394118/angularjs-directive-scope-not-resolved-attr-name-is-not-defined-error/28394192#28394192) for more info.

Comment: .directive("checkboxGroup", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            // Determine initial checked boxes
            if (scope.array.indexOf(scope.item.value) !== -1) {
                elem[0].checked = true;
            }

Comment: // Update array on click
            elem.bind('click', function() {
    scope.frame={};
                var index = scope.array.indexOf(scope.item.value);
                // Add if checked
                if (elem[0].checked) {
                    if (index === -1) scope.array.push(scope.item.value);
                }

Comment: // Remove if unchecked
                else {
                    if (index !== -1) scope.array.splice(index, 1);
                }
                // Sort and update DOM display
               /* scope.$apply(scope.array.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return a - b
                }));*/
    
            });
        }
    }
})

Comment: where do you use this working directive `checkboxGroup`? better show me the html template using `checkboxGroup`

Comment: above 3 comment contain that directive for working example.i have put the checkboxsGroup directive below the checkboxGroup direrctive in my module.

Comment: <div ng-repeat="item in list">
                                            <input type="checkbox" checkbox-group />
                                            <label>{{item.value}}</label> </div><input type="hidden" name="checkboxvalues" ng-model="frame.lens_type" ng-init="frame.lens_type=array">

Comment: this code for another directive :                                                             <div  ng-repeat="colors in frame_product_options.color_list">
             <input type="checkbox" checkboxs-group />{{colors.color_name}}
                                                     <center> <input type="button" name="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"  ng-click="frame_color_img(colors.id)" value="Save"></center></div> <input type="hidden" name="clrcheckboxvalues" ng-model="frame.clr_code" ng-init="frame.clr_code=arrays">

Comment: it seems you define `array` in your controller's scope, is this correct?

Comment: yes bro i forgot that,i just define only for array like this.         $scope.array = [];
      $scope.array_ = angular.copy($scope.array);
      $scope.list = [{
       //"id": 1,
       "value": "single vision",
      }, {
       //"id": 3,
       "value": "biofical",
      }, {
       //"id": 5,
       "value": "zero power"
      }];

Comment: now the root cause is clear. You define `scope.array` in your controller, that's why `checkboxGroup` can work. However you didn't define `scope.arrays` in your controller and directive `checkboxsGroup`, so it has no idea what `scope.arrays` is, which leads to an undefined error.

Comment: I have posted my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you got undefined error, you didn't define `scope.arrays` in directive's outter scope. For example, if you define `scope.arrays` in your controller's scope, the error would disappear.

Comment: i have define like this, $scope.arrays = []; then "Error: scope.item is undefined" while run this..

Comment: yeah, it's similar. Item is not defined in your controller or directive. When you say `item`, which element or object you are referring to?

Comment: OUTPUT:         throw                        "Error: scope.item is undefined"  this error and                                                                                               In my console                                                                                        clr_code
 
 []          //empty
lens_type
 
 ["single vision", "zero power"]
0
 
 "single vision"
1
 
 "zero power"

Comment: bro.. i am new to angular so i can't easily understood this error issue.can you guide me to overcome this issue.

Comment: `scope.arrays.indexOf(scope.item.value`, check this line of code. If you want to access `scope.arrays` or `scope.item`, these variables must be declared or initialized. `Scope` is an Angular concept, which is used to handle data bindings. So currently, Angular has no idea what `scope.item` is as you didn't initialize it.,

Comment: i got it bro..thanks a lot..this is my problem  if (scope.arrays.indexOf(scope.colors.color_name) !== -1) {

Comment: Great to hear that it's fixed now. You may want to mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: thanks bro to spend your time for me..It's working perfect..

Comment: Thanks man, wish you a good day :)

Comment: nice to meet you bro..thanks